# Gradle Project Build Order For Maven Tasks

Tags: maven, gradle

Consider the following multi-project build script:

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  group = "myorg"
  version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

project(':client') {
  dependencies {
    compile 'myorg:shared:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
}
```

With the following files:

```
├── build.gradle
├── client
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── myorg
│                   └── client
│                       └── MyOrgClient.java
├── settings.gradle
└── shared
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── myorg
                    └── shared
                        └── MyOrgObj.java
```

In the above files MyOrgClient.java includes `myorg.shared.MyOrgObj` and settings.gradle has the single line `include 'client', 'shared'`

**Problem**

The project/task build order for maven related tasks like installing locally and deploying to remote repositories does not take into account the implied project dependency.  Because gradle does not know that `'myorg:shared:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'` is created by `project(':shared')`, the build order is `:client -> :shared` and causes errors like the one below:

```
$ gradle install
:client:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':client:compile'.
> Could not find myorg:shared:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      myorg:client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

**Question:** 
Is there a standard way to deal with this problem?  I have tried these solutions without success:

- Using `mustRunAfter` but ran into problems with tasks not existing yet. I also don't think this would scale well with a large number of projects
- Adding `archives project(':shared')` to the client's dependencies
- Adding `compile project(':shared')` to the client's dependencies <strike>and then removing it from the generated pom.  Unfortunately this doesn't add the dependency to the install task or artifactoryPublish</strike>  ***Edit:** This actually was the solution. A project dependency will provide the correct version/name/group in the generated pom.xml so the explicit group:name:version dependency is not needed*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the dependencies between the projects more or less the same way as in Maven:

For example like this:

```
project(':app') {
  apply plugin: 'ear'
  dependencies {
    compile project (':webgui')
    compile project (':service')
  }
}
```

But you need to define the settings.gradle which contains the modules like this:

```
include 'app'
include 'domain'
include 'service'
include 'service-client'
include 'webgui'
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I had a settings.gradle with the line `include 'client', 'shared'`.  I'm not sure that breaking it into separate lines changes anything

Comment: This works.  They key misunderstanding that I had was that I wasn't aware a project dependency would create a pom.xml with the correct group/name/version information.  I think this was because of an early problem I had were the dependent project did not have a version or group defined.