# Gradle Module Build Ordering

Tags: java, gradle

I have project structure, that has modules of

```
root
 |_ core
 |_ integration-test
 |_ web
```

**web** module is dependent on the **core** module. **integration-test** module is dependent on **web** module.

settings.gradle

```
include 'core', 'web', 'integration-test'
```

When I execute gradle build

```
./gradleW clean build
```

By default, gradle will build the project in alpha neumeric order, so it will build like this

```
:core:clean
:integration-test:clean 
:web:clean 
...
```

How can I override the ordering so that it should build like this?

```
:core:clean
:web:clean
:integration-test:clean 
...
```

Note: To test the ordering, I have failing test in **web** and **integration-test** modules, unfornately though integration-tests always comes first before the web.

Comment: You can define dependency for that like this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978020/gradle-project-build-order-for-maven-tasks

Comment: I already doing that so it compiles successfully between modules dependencies, but my concern is the build order

Comment: @richersoon did you get the solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try add dependency in integration-test to core and web module.
Also, seems that you can not override build ordering, because it depends on module dependencies.